# What is the difference between getHeight and getScaledHeight in bitmap?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

What is the difference between getHeight and getScaledHeight in a bitmap?

Comment: Is there a documentation which could answer that?

Comment: `getHeight` gives the height of the bitmap in pixels, `getScaledHeight` gives the height in inches. According to the documentation: "Convenience method that returns the height of this bitmap divided by the density scale factor. Returns the bitmap's height multiplied by the ratio of the target density to the bitmap's source density"